# May i know what is wrong with my code

Tags: jquery

please help me figure it out what is wrong with my code. i'm trying to append new  row on my table with an id and a class. Here is my code

```
function hideDiv() {
    document.getElementById('addLayout').style.display = "none";
    $(".tb1_tb").append("<tr><td id="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td></tr>");
}
```

Comment: use single quotes inside append.

Answer (score 3):

There is error in `append`, you have to escape quotes inside quotes or use single quotes outside.

```
function hideDiv() {
    document.getElementById('addLayout').style.display = "none";
    $(".tb1_tb").append('<tr><td id="dropzone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></td></tr>');
}
```

**OR**

Escape the quotes by preceding them by `\`

```
$(".tb1_tb").append("<tr><td id=\"dropzone\" ondrop=\"drop(event)\" ondragover=\"allowDrop(event)\"></td></tr>");
```